# Could someone explain how to install SoundManager2

Tags: html, xhtml, css

I've never been able to figure this out!

Yeah I copy the java script in but what is the html code required and css??

Their website doesn't explain any of that (unless I am missing it!!)

If someone could please break it down for me I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

Actually used this in a site before, this is what I have in my code:

In the header, assuming you have it installed in the `/soundmanager2/` directory:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="soundmanager2/soundmanager2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        soundManager.url = 'soundmanager2/';
        soundManager.useHTML5Audio = false;
        soundManager.useFlashBlock = false;
        soundManager.debugMode = false;
    </script>
```

Then on each element you want to play a sound with on click, include this attribute:

`onClick="soundManager.play('Name','path/to/filename.mp3')"`

Or you can simply call `soundManager.play` wherever you want.

Comment: Is it possible my problem is because I am testing this locally on my computer? maybe if I upload is to my server??

Comment: Sometimes Javascript is disabled when running from a local file, is that the issue?

Comment: nope, i tried uploading it. and all the came up was some sort of debugging code...

Comment: Would probably be useful to post any errors that come up in the JS console here.

Comment: "nope, i tried uploading it. and all the came up was some sort of debugging code..", lol that is exactly the type of info that would be beneficial in helping you. Please post.

Answer (score 0):

Granted it is not the easiest interface in the world in terms of copy and paste code and your good to go.

However all of the demos on there site have all the CSS / HTML you need to get started writting your own themes and templates.

There site is mor about the JS behind the scenes then the look of the interface.

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/play-mp3-links/ (as an example)

Although I am sure you were hoping for downloadable code I hope this at least gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I don't know what I am missing, I am just trying to get it to play any sound on a blank page with no styling.  I'm sure that I am missing something very minor but i have wasted hours on this today haha